# OpenX JSON SerDe properties paths (AWS Athena Glue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am manually creating tables in the AWS Glue data catalog. Is the SerDe property 'paths' required?  I've noticed that the crawlers add this property and it is shown in the AWS docs. What does it do?

It appears to be a list of columns names but I can query my data from Athena without providing it. Should I add it anyway?

[Amazon Athena - OpenX JSON SerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html#openxjson)

Comment: It's optional!!

Comment: @Jonny you ever found out what the `paths` property does?

Comment: @KarlAnka afraid not, I left it out and have had no issues.